# Best Approach to have a pop-up window when user click on a left side link

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, html, hyperlink

I am working on a Team Site collection inside sharepoint 2013.

now i am trying to deliver the following requirements:-

1. Inside our root team site home page. to add 5 left-side links for showing instruction inside a popup windows .
2. the links will be "HR Procedures", "Dress code", etc..
3. when users click on one of the link a popup window will open showing the instructions.

[image]

Now i tried the following:-

- i created a new Wikipage library.
- inside the advance settings i set to open item in a dialog:-

[image]

- then i created 5 pages inside the wikilibrary, and i add  links to the pages inside the left-side links.
- but when users click on the links the instruction pages will be shown directly inside the main windows and not inside a dialog.

so can anyone adivce on this please ? should i use JavaScript to achieve what i am looking for ??

Comment: I would use javascript with the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)` Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: As far as I am aware, the "Launch forms in a dialog" settings for lists/libraries specifically applies to the New, Edit and Display forms for the library.  A Wikipage in a library would count as *content*, and not a form. If you were to select one of your Wikipages and choose to "view properties", *that* would open in a dialog.

Comment: @DylanCristy so what are the options i am left with ? should i consider another list type not of type wiki page ? or i should keep using the wiki page and try doing my point using JavaScript ??

Comment: @ErinL so i need to add the related javaScript inside a script editor web part ? not sure how to attach the related javaScritp inside the link you provide to my links??

Comment: @DylanCristy now i have noted is that even if i add a library which uses forms (such as announcement) this will not work.as the display form will not be opened inside popup if i add a link to the item inside the left-side navigation... it will only open on a dialog if i am inside the list views and i click on the item.

Comment: @ErinL can you please advice on how i can benefit from "_SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);_" to achieve my requirement? now i usually use "_SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);_" inside custom JavaScript .. so do you mean i need to write a custom script and reference this script inside my master page, where this script will fire when the user click on the related Quick Launch links ?? if this is your appraoch then i can see a problem is that i need to explore the markup for the quick launch,

Comment: @ErinL .. and get the markup for the related links.. now this markup may change in the future if we apply an update to sharepoint.. is this correct ? now i was trying to find a more standard appraoch to benefit from existing list settings, etc . but if i can not achieve this using list settings options , then using a custom script inside my master page is the only approach to go with,, did i understand your replies/approach  correctly??

Comment: @ErinL can you provide more details about using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options) to achieve my requirements ? should i write this inside a script ? and attached the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options) with specific links?

Comment: I'm under a time crunch at work, so I can't write up samples right now. Please look for example with google to get you started and let me know where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following code at `script editor` on your page to open a link in modal dialog

```
< script >
function openDialog(pageUrl) {
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Title of the Dialog',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
width: 500,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
</ script >
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('http://SharePointSite/Lists/WebEvents/NewForm.aspx');">Central Admin</a>
```

For more details [Open a link via Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

**[Update]**

As a workaround you can add this code at you script editor in your home page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script >
function openDialog(pageUrl) {
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Qassas Dialog',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
width: 500,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}

$(".ms-core-listMenu-item").click(function(e) { 

openDialog(e.target.href);
//$(".menu-item").removeAttr('href');

return false;

 });
</script >
```

Comment: but is there a way to force this to work on a left-side link rather than rendering a new <a> insdie the script editor ,, this is basically my question

Comment: are you mean the left navigation ?

Comment: yes exactly the built-in left side navigation links..

Comment: let me try something in my side , if it worked i will update you

Comment: appreciate this ..thnx

Comment: @johnG These are the details of what I meant. If M.Qassas doesn't figure it out, tag me and let me know.

Comment: @M.Qassas I'm thinking js to loop through links in the quick launch and override them with onclicks. What are you thinking?

Comment: @ErinL you are right and that what I tried to do now , but if you already have this code I will appreciate if you post it as answer to help John faster , thanks for your cooperation

Comment: I don't have it. It was just the only solution I could think of.

Comment: No problem sister @ErinL I will try it and I will update my answer if I got it  , thanks again for your useful thinking :)

Comment: @Erin thanks for your concern will keep you posted..

Comment: @M.Qassas did u have the chance to check this further? now i am thinking of adding a wiki library app>>create the pages>>inside the quick launch to add links for the wiki pages.then to explore the markup from the quick launch links, and add jQuery code which will render the page inside "_SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)_".. but the problem is that i can not find an easy way to get how to jQuery will capture the quick launch links, as each link will not have a specific id to reference it

Comment: @johnG I developed a code that shows the left navigation as a modal pop-up dialog , but I put it on the home page.  is this match your requirements ?

Comment: the scenario as the following at your site home page you have a left navigation , so it let it open as modal  , is this enough if no tell me more to modify my code

Comment: unfortunately, the comments not hold the full code let us continue at chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48465/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-cant-rename-a-master-page-or-edit-using-sharep

Answer (score -1):

By Left side link you mean the quick launch/current navigation?

Any of the links you put there can have the "open link in a new window"
[image]

Any link you place in a page with INSERT - LINK can have the "open in a new page" inside the link settings

[image]

Comment: but "open in new window" will either open the link inside a new tab, or inside a new browser based on users' browsers setting.. it does not mean open in popup. and yes when i am talking about left side navigation i mean the quick luck navigations..

Comment: when you install software to block pop-ups, they do block also automatic new windows (some pop ups have the full browser toolbar), this is why I interpreted pop up = new window